# Is it illegal to refuse a man to enter a Women's Only Poker Tournament?

Tags: united-states, discrimination, new-jersey, sex-discrimination, transgender

I read a story about [men entering women's only poker tournaments](https://www.pokerwebsites.com/women/men-vs-women/).

One example from the article states that *eight men joined the field of over 1000 female poker players in the $1,000 buy-in 2009 WSOP Ladies Championship*, and that **Harrah’s Entertainment was obligated by law to allow the men to take part in the field, even though they were gently asked to leave (to no avail)**.

Another example mentions a man who won the 2009 Borgata Poker Open [Ladies No-Limit Hold'em - Event 7](https://www.cardplayer.com/poker-news/7537-man-wins-ladies-event-at-the-2009-borgata-poker-open-in-atlantic-city-nj). That article states that "***Most states have banned casinos from applying sex-based discrimination to their poker tournaments, but a polite request is usually honored by male cardroom patrons***".

Is it illegal to refuse a man to sign up to a Women's Only Poker Tournament? What is an example of one of the laws from any state? What exactly is the illegal point, and what is the penalty?

Does the man need to do anything special, such as to state that he is a woman? If he says "I'm a man and I want to sign up" is it still illegal to refuse him to enter the tournament?

Is simply *hosting* a "Ladies Only" tournament illegal? Or is the *refusal to enter because of gender* the illegal part?

Comment: Here in FL the same thing goes on, an unfortunate side effect of anti-discrimination laws.  It used to be a fun thing among poker buddies.  As a guy, the loser of a contest might have to enter a women's only poker tourney and have to wear a dress and a wig.  They were expected to dump their chips.

Comment: The fun went out of that sexist move when a women beat all the men in a world tournament.

Comment: @GeorgeWhite who was the woman and which tournament?

Comment: Annie Duke  World Series of Poker Tournament 2004